# Carregar DIV automaticamente com Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Preciso que uma DIV de medicamentos seja preenchida no momento que o usuário escolha uma das opções em um combobox (subtipo).

No meu *index* tenho a combobox, onde criei o script do Ajax conforme abaixo:

```
$('#subtipo').change( // o subtipo está localizado nesta página.
    function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",  
            url: "AJAX_buscaMedicamentos.php?id="+id, //aqui faço os "selects" dos medicamenos
            success: function(data) {
                // Preciso dizer que a div a ser preenchida de ID "box_medicamentos" está em outra pagina, nomeada medicamentos.php.
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Agora a tabela a ser preenchida **não** esta no meu *index*, está em outra página chamada `medicamentos.php` (essa página aparece no meu index utilizando o `JS` `TabbedPanelsTab`).

Na pagina `medicamentos.php` a DIV deve ser preenchida conforme abaixo:

```
echo '<div class="tbline titlecel"><div class="tbcel1"></div><div class="tbcel3">Medicamento</div><div class="tbcel2">Via Administração</div><div class="tbcel2">Dose</div><div class="tbcel2">Unid. Medida</div><div class="tbcel3">Dias Aplicação</div><div class="tbcel3">Ciclos Aplicação</div><div class="tbcel3">Diluente/Reconstituinte</div><div class="tbcel2">Dose</div><div class="tbcel2">Unid. Medida</div></div>';

while (($exibe = oci_fetch_array($parsed_medicamento, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    $NR_SEQUENCIA            = $exibe ["NR_SEQUENCIA"]; 
    $DS_MATERIAL             = $exibe ["DS_MATERIAL"];  
    $DS_VIA_APLICACAO        = $exibe ["DS_VIA_APLICACAO"];
    $QT_DOSE                 = $exibe ["QT_DOSE"];
    $DS_UNIDADE_MEDIDA       = $exibe ["DS_UNIDADE_MEDIDA"];
    $DS_DIAS_APLICACAO       = $exibe ["DS_DIAS_APLICACAO"];
    $DS_CICLOS_APLICACAO     = $exibe ["DS_CICLOS_APLICACAO"];
    $DS_DILUENTE             = $exibe ["DS_DILUENTE"];
    $QT_DOSE_DILUENTE        = $exibe ["QT_DOSE_DILUENTE"];
    $DS_UNID_MEDIDA_DILUENTE = $exibe ["DS_UNID_MEDIDA_DILUENTE"];

    echo '<div class="tbline"><div class="tbcel1 excluir"><a href="?exclui=ok&id='.$idsession.'&nr_sequencia='.$NR_SEQUENCIA.'"><font color="#FFFFFF">excluir</font></a></div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_MATERIAL.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$DS_VIA_APLICACAO.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$QT_DOSE.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$DS_UNIDADE_MEDIDA.'</div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_DIAS_APLICACAO.'</div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_CICLOS_APLICACAO.'</div><div class="tbcel3">'.$DS_DILUENTE.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$QT_DOSE_DILUENTE.'</div><div class="tbcel2">'.$DS_UNID_MEDIDA_DILUENTE.'</div></div>';
}
```

Sendo que faço os *selects* na página `AJAX_buscaMedicamentos.php?id=XX` como faço para que a DIV da página `medicamentos.php` seja preenchida?

> Obs.: A DIV se encontra em outra página `medicamentos.php`, pois é nessa página onde o usuário vai revisar os medicamentos que irão aparecer.

Comment: Pelo que vejo `data` é uma string com HTML certo? Nesse caso `$('#id-da-div').html(data);` faz o que queres. Já experimentaste isso?

Comment: Mas conforme falei, a DIV se encontra em outra página (medicamentos.php), e o script fica na minha home onde tem o combo #subtipo onde o usuario faz a escolha e conforme a escolha deverá ser preenchido a DIV em medicamentos.php

Answer (score 1):

```
  $.ajax({      
            type:"POST", 
            crossDomain: false,
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            url: " medicamentos.php?parametro="+(Variável),

            success: function(dados)
                {   //load_modal("#Mload");
                    $("box_medicamentos").empty();  
                    $("box_medicamentos").html(dados);              
                }   
}
```

Comment: Desse modo vc chamara a segunda pagina e poderá adicionar os valores na sua div. voce tambem poderia enviar uma resposta em formato json da pagina medicamentos.php.

Comment: Mas e as consultas (select) que faço dos medicamentos na página "AJAX_buscaMedicamentos.php" conforme o ID da página principal?

Comment: Este exemplo que coloquei,  precisar ser acionado  após a seleção da opção do combobox, voce estará enviando o que foi selecionado pelo método GET